# tags: security vs. computer-security

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security), [computer-security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-security) seems to represent the same thing. I think we should make one a synonym for the other. The first one is shorter whereas the second one is more explicit.

What do you think? Should they become synonyms? If yes, which one should be the main tag?

Comment: I usually prefer the longer ones, the shorter being the synonyms.

Comment: Yeah, I say we make computer-security the tag, security the synonym. In the context of this site, they (should) mean the same thing.

Comment: What other kind of security would we be talking about? This is the computer science stackexchange, so the word computer is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

In [computer-security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-security), the word “computer” is redundant at best and misleading at worst. You don't really secure a computer, but a computer system (involving software, policies, network setup and other elements that aren't “computer” per se). The tag should be [security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security).

There are tags in which the word “computer” may be justified, such as [computer-networks](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-networks) (as opposed to kinds of graphs) and [computer-architecture](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture), and even then I'm unconvinced: shouldn't that be [networks](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networks) and [hardware-architecture](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-architecture)?

---

Given the lack of counter-argument, and given that I couldn't see a difference in usage between [computer-security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-security) and [security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security), the two tags are now merged under [security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security).

Comment: Seems reasonable argument to me.

Comment: ps: I think it is best to leave discussion about other tags to another question. May I suggest that you move the later part to two new questions. (I think the ambiguity of word networks in CS justifies the prefix.)

Comment: @Kaveh We don't need a meta question about every single tag. Renaming a tag is very easy, unlike splitting or mass-retagging, so we need to decide early on the choice of meaning but don't need to care so much about the choice of name.

Comment: There can be different views about each tag, it is better to keep the discussion focused on one. There is no harm in having separate meta discussion for each. I agree with your argument in the first paragraph but disagree with the second one. I have upvoted your answer while I disagree with what you way about other tags. To avoid this kind of problems I think the discussions should be kept separate if possible. If I start to explain the reason why I disagree with the second one the discussion will loose focus and will be harder to derive any conclusion.

Comment: Dito; agree with first paragraph, don't with second.